# Add a conditional to ng keypress

Tags: angular, typescript

When a text input contains a specific value, I want to show a div.

For my template I have:

```
<input type="text" id="jobTitle" 
(click)="autoCompleteClick()"
(keypress)="autoCompleteKeypress()" name="autocomplete" 
placeholder="Job Title" value="" >
```

My thinking was the keypress would run the autoCompleteKeyPress function which looks like this:

```
autoCompleteKeypress() {
    if (this.jobTitle == 'bar' || this.jobTitle == 'Bar'){
        alert('BOO!');
    } 
}
```

At the moment i'm just testing with with an alert to get it working.

My full component is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'sign-up',
    templateUrl: './sign-up.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../variables.less', './sign-up.component.less']
})

export class SignUpComponent {
    imgPath = 'assets/images/';
    //acInput = document.getElementById('jobTitle');

    @Input() jobTitle : string;


    autoCompleteKeypress() {
        if (this.jobTitle == 'bar' || this.jobTitle == 'Bar'){
        alert('BOO!');
    } 
}
```

Very new to Angular2 and Typescript in general so any ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: add a running example on jsfiddle, plunker, jsbin or your alternative, so others don't have to copy paste your code.

Comment: do you want show div while user entering certain while in the Textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need to do is hide and show `div` based on specific input value I will suggest you to utilize basic [Two-way binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---) mechanism with [NgIf Directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) like follows

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="jobTitle" id="jobTitle"  name="autocomplete" placeholder="Job Title" value="" >
<div *ngIf="jobTitle === 'bar' || jobTitle === 'Bar'">
    Contain to display
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. Decided to go with the ngif rather than using a function in the component.

Answer (score 0):

We don't get input value into `this` by assigning to id . You need to use `NgModel` for that . But in this case you don't really need to add to class variable .

Change HTML to this :

```
<input type="text" id="jobTitle" 
(click)="autoCompleteClick()"
(keypress)="autoCompleteKeypress($event)" name="autocomplete" 
placeholder="Job Title" value="" >
```

Inside component

```
autoCompleteKeypress(event) {
     const jobTitle = event.target.value;
    if (jobTitle == 'bar' || jobTitle == 'Bar'){
        alert('BOO!');
    } 
}
```